# Differences between GCC/Clang when linking

Tags: linker, embedded, clang, objcopy, arm-none-eabi-gcc

Because of vastly better C++ compile times I've recently added the option to compile a project for an ARM Cortex-M4 microcontroller with Clang instead of the arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain. The whole process ran quite smoothly and I quickly had working ELF and HEX files. It wasn't until yesterday evening that I noticed that the ELF files actually differ quite a lot...

Before I continue let's inspect the ELF produced by GCC to get some kind of baseline.

GCC's ELF contains the following sections (apart from debug stuff)

```
    Section Headers:
      [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
      [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
      [ 1] .vector_table     PROGBITS        08000000 010000 000010 00   A  0   0  4
      [ 2] .version          NOBITS          08000010 010010 000010 00  WA  0   0  1
      [ 3] .text             PROGBITS        08000020 010020 000138 00  AX  0   0  4
      [ 4] .rodata           PROGBITS        08000158 010158 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
      [ 5] .data             PROGBITS        20000000 010158 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
      [ 6] .data2            PROGBITS        10000000 010158 000000 00   W  0   0  1
      [ 7] .bss              NOBITS          20000000 020000 00038c 00  WA  0   0 512
      [ 8] .bss2             PROGBITS        2000038c 010158 000000 00   W  0   0  1
      [ 9] ._user_heap_stack NOBITS          2000038c 020000 000e04 00  WA  0   0  1
```

But despite .data and .bss being marked with an "A" (alloc) flag only loads the following

```
    Program Headers:
      Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
      LOAD           0x010000 0x08000000 0x08000000 0x00158 0x00158 RWE 0x10000
      LOAD           0x000000 0x20000000 0x20000000 0x00000 0x01190 RW  0x10000

     Section to Segment mapping:
      Segment Sections...
       00     .vector_table .version .text 
       01     .bss ._user_heap_stack
```

So far so good.

The problem emerged when I tried to create binaries from an ELF produced by Clang. Those files where huge in size (256MB) which is nowhere near what I had expected. Now, if you're not familiar with ARM microcontrollers, they usually contain FLASH and RAM memory at very different address locations (e.g. 0x0800'0000 for FLASH and 0x2000'0000 for RAM as seen above). So I already had some suspicion on what's going on... I checked my linker script and put a NOLOAD directive on every section which goes solely to RAM. Problem solved?

Well... not really. In fact my binaries grew even bigger.

Let's take a look at Clang's ELF. It's bugging me a little that Clang doesn't seem to remove the section for unwinding (ARM.exidx) although I compile with -fno-unwind-tables and -gc-sections but ok, I can live with those 16B.

```
    Section Headers:
      [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
      [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
      [ 1] .vector_table     PROGBITS        08000000 001000 000010 00   A  0   0  4
      [ 2] .version          PROGBITS        08000010 001010 000010 00   A  0   0  1
      [ 3] .text             PROGBITS        08000020 001020 000334 00  AX  0   0  4
      [ 4] .rodata           PROGBITS        08000354 001354 000000 00  AX  0   0  1
      [ 5] .ARM.exidx        ARM_EXIDX       08000354 001354 000010 00  AL  3   0  4
      [ 6] .preinit_array    PROGBITS        08000364 001364 000000 00   A  0   0  1
      [ 7] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      08000364 001364 000004 04  WA  0   0  4
      [ 8] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      08000368 001368 000004 04  WA  0   0  4
      [ 9] .data             PROGBITS        20000000 002000 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
      [10] .data2            PROGBITS        10000000 002000 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
      [11] .bss              NOBITS          20000000 002000 0001ac 00  WA  0   0 512
      [12] .bss2             PROGBITS        200001ac 002000 000000 00  WA  0   0  1
      [13] ._user_heap_stack PROGBITS        200001ac 002000 000e04 00  WA  0   0  1
```

Now this is where it gets interesting and where I have no clue whats happening. What is GNU_RELRO and GNU_STACK and how does it end up there? Why is GNU_STACK at address 0. Any chance this entry is bloating my binaries?

```
    Program Headers:
      Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
      LOAD           0x001000 0x08000000 0x08000000 0x00364 0x00364 R E 0x1000
      LOAD           0x001364 0x08000364 0x08000364 0x00008 0x00008 RW  0x1000
      GNU_RELRO      0x001364 0x08000364 0x08000364 0x00008 0x00c9c R   0x1
      GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0
      EXIDX          0x001354 0x08000354 0x08000354 0x00010 0x00010 R   0x4

     Section to Segment mapping:
      Segment Sections...
       00     .vector_table .version .text .rodata .ARM.exidx 
       01     .preinit_array .init_array .fini_array 
       02     .preinit_array .init_array .fini_array 
       03     
       04     .rodata .ARM.exidx
```

Further questions:

- How is GCC able to remove all the RAM sections despite them
  previously not having a NOLOAD directive in the linker script?
- Running size on Clang's ELF counts the minimum stack size I define in the linker script to the .data section whereas on GCC's ELF it doesn't. How is that? My linker script contains a section which looks like this

```
    ._user_heap_stack (NOLOAD) :
    {
      . = ALIGN(8);
      PROVIDE ( end = . );
      PROVIDE ( _end = . );
      . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
      . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
      . = ALIGN(8);
    } >RAM
```

- but to my knowledge this should only "check" that there is at least
  enough RAM left to cover my defined minimum heap and stack size. This
  section doesn't actually contain anything so how can it be counted to
  .data?

I know that I could remove unwanted sections with objcopy when actually creating the binaries, but I'd really like to understand those subtle differences between GCC and Clang.

/edit
I just noticed that my ._user_heap_stack section has different types depending on the compiler (NOBITS vs PROGBITS). Guess that explains why it's counted to .data...

/edit
Now a (potential) bug over @ LLVM
https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46299

/edit
And closed as of lld 10.0.1
https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46225